# xUnit InlineData unexpected result

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, xunit

I've got the following class I'm trying to unit test (example class):

```
using System;

public class Checker
{
    public bool Check<T>(T valueA, T valueB)
    {
        if (typeof(T) != typeof(string))
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I call `new Checker().Check(null, "test")` it correctly returns `true` but when I use xUnit with `InlineData` as follows:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(null, "test")]
[InlineData("test", null)]
public void TestChecker<T>(T valueA, T valueB)
{
   var checker = new Checker();

   Assert.True(checker.Check(valueA, valueB));
}
```

Both tests should pass but they don't - instead a `NotSupportedException` exception is thrown on the first test. According to the Test Explorer... this was passed on the first test:

`Namespace.TestChecker<Object>(valueA: null, valueB: "test")` - why is `T` type of `object` instead of `string` as when I call it directly and how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Because compiler infers the `T` to `string` in `checker.Check(valueA, valueB)`, and `null` is valid value for `string`

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski the question is not why when calling `new Checker().Check(null, "test")` `T` is of type `string` - that's pretty obvious. The question is why does that not happen when I use `[InlineData(null, "test")]` (but happens when I use `[InlineData("test", null)]`

Comment: _The second test should fail but it's not_ the second test throws a `NotSupportedException` and passes, according to your assert. The first will fail. Do you know, what you want to test and see as expected behavior?

Comment: I guess, that it's just a compiler rule to determine the type to infer based on parameters values. To be more precise, this paragraph [Finding the best common type of a set of expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#finding-the-best-common-type-of-a-set-of-expressions) explains that

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I'm still not sure you got the question... the type is clear: it's a `string`. When calling `new Checker().Check(null, "test") `T` is definitely a string. So when calling it via `xUnit` `InlineData` `T` should also be a `string`, but it's not.

Comment: Have you solved the problem? If so, how?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Only thing I could find is don't use `InlineData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok actually there is a better way of achieving this while maintaining `InlineData`:

```
[Theory]
[InlineData(null, "test")]
[InlineData("test", null)]
public void TestChecker<T>(T valueA, T valueB)
{
   var checker = new Checker();

   Assert.True(checker.Check((dynamic) valueA, (dynamic) valueB));
}
```

Although this is not the prettiest because `Test Explorer` will still show `TestChecker<Object>(valueA: null, valueB: "test")` but it works...